# Need perfact Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I need to extract information form a text using regex for statements like bellow

```
#1. 02/14/2013 05:21 pm - Safee Safeeul Bashir
- Status changed from New to In Progress

#2. 02/14/2013 10:43 pm - Safee Safeeul Bashir
- Status changed from In Progress to Resolved
- CL set to 1203474

#3. 08/16/2013 02:30 am - Mondal Amit Kumar
Task was automatically close beacuse last update was more than two months and the issue passed
```

From here I want to extract the date and time where the status is changed to resolve.
For example for this one the date with `#2 **02/14/2013 10:43 pm**`

Comment: I tried to extract 02/14/2013 10:43 pm based on String Resolved. Please check there is Resolved in second para.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\s\d\d:\d\d\s[ap]m(?=.*(\n?\r?).*Resolved)
```

[See it on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37ct0)

Answer (score 0):

The regex can be

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s[pa]m
```

Comment: It is maching the string. But Need to extract the date from here. And moreover There is three dates. it is matching all the date. I need to match only the resolve date. please check the context again.

Comment: I don't know what the language do you use so can't suggest flag. for example if you use Perl it will be `my @dates = $text =~ /(myregex)/gi`

Comment: Its for VBA Excel Macro

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this language. But to capture something from text using regexp you should use `()` brackets so use `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s[pa]m)` or get `Value` of the matching. I am pretty sure that VBA can do it.

Comment: I almost got this. I there is a line break. I need to capture this.